# How to take any input from the users in capital letters even if the user is entering it in small letters?

Tags: python, string, windows, uppercase, capitalize

I am trying to generate a story using python. For this I'm trying to take the input from the users for some questions. The scenario I'm trying to get is that whenever the user enters the input, then it is displayed on the output screen in capital letters.
But what happens is that the text is diplayed in small letters.
Here is the sample of the code

```
message1 = input(" my name is: ")
message2 = input(" i am from: ") 
message3 = input(" i love to eat: ")
print( " My name is " + message1.upper() + " I am from " + message2.upper() + " I love to eat " +  message3.upper())
```

I expect `My name is SANDEEP` when the user enters `sandeep`, but I get `sandeep`.

Comment: And what is wrong with your current code?

Comment: Sir, The problem is that with this code i am not getting the desired result. Everything is OK . But what i want is the input that any user is entering should display as capital letters. @ Daniel Roseman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this following code for console app. I am converting the input after reading it whole. But you can do the job quiet easily and get your desired result(Converting every character as you enter to  uppercase) when you'll implement it in web applications( by using html and javascript there).

```
import os
message1 = input(" MY NAME IS: ")
os.system('cls') 
message1="MY NAME IS : "+message1.upper()
res=message1+"\n"
message2 = input(res+"I AM FROM: ") 
os.system('cls') 
res+="I AM FROM : "+message2.upper()+"\n"
message2="I AM FROM : "+message2.upper()
message3 = input(res+"I LOVE TO EAT: ")
os.system('cls') 
res+="I LOVE TO EAT : "+message3.upper()+"\n"
message3="I LOVE TO EAT: "+message3.upper()
print(res+"\n\n\n"+ message1 +"\t"+message2+"\t"+message3)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked as required. Got the desired result.@user8994414

Comment: Welcome Sandeep

Answer (score 0):

So, this will only work on Linux systems and only with ASCII characters:

```
import termios
import sys

def uppercase_input(prompt):
    sys.stdout.write(prompt)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    old = termios.tcgetattr(sys.stdout.fileno())
    new = old[:]
    new[1] |= termios.OLCUC
    termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdout.fileno(), termios.TCSANOW, new)
    try:
        return input().upper()
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(sys.stdout.fileno(), termios.TCSANOW, old)


result = uppercase_input("all uppercase? ")
print("yes: {}".format(result))
```

This uses some interesting ancient settings to convert I/O to/from uppercase from the old times when there were terminals only supporting upper-case ASCII.

From `man tcsetattr`:

> OLCUC  (not in POSIX) Map lowercase characters to uppercase on output.

So this solution is not really portable.

For a fully portable solution, you would need to implement echoing yourself.

Comment: And what about the windows system. Well i am using Visual Studio preloaded with Python interpreter. So how to implement this with that?

Comment: @SandeepAnand You have to implement echoing (= the re-output of what was typed) yourself, and I don’t know how and if that works on Windows.

Comment: Sir, i have studied about Echo echo is an old unix/DOS/shell command that simply types back whatever text you type in. like a print command.. SO how can i use it here?

Comment: No, that’s not what I meant. I don’t know the details on windows. On POSIX, the terminal has an option to "echo back" every single character typed *without* having the application involved. This is what is used during e.g. ``input()`` to show what was typed. It is often used in combination with line buffering. What you need is to turn off line buffering and echoing on the terminal and handle both yourself.

Comment: @ Jonas Wielicki OK  Sir. Thanks a lot. By the way I got the solution. Anyway thanks for the help.